# ChatGPT randomly adding extra unnecessary stuff to output despite asking for just the JSON format

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a goal of making the ChatGPT 4.0 API output something in a consistent format, i.e. in a JSON-format.

**desired output example**

```
{
   "name": "Jon",
   "last_nane": "Doe"
}
```

**actual output example**

````
```json // here it randomly adds backticks and json
{
   "name": "Jon",
   "last_name": "Doe"
}
``` // here it randomly adds 3 backticks
````

**my actual prompting is**

````
Translate the following text to the languages matching the language codes and output them in JSON format.

Important:
 * Do NOT use apostrophes/backticks in the output
 * Do NOT start with ```json
 * Do NOT end with ```
 * Do NOT explain anything in the output
 * If there are any exceptions, then do NOT translate them
 * If the input is empty, then the output should be empty

Use exactly the same OUTPUT format as the below:

----------------
INPUT: Dette er en Dansk oversættelse
LANGUAGECODES: da-DK, en-US, nl-NL
EXCEPTIONS: Dansk
OUTPUT: [{"da-DK":"Dette er en Dansk oversættelse"},{"en-US":"This is an Dansk translation"},{"nl-NL":"Dit is een Dansk vertaling"}]

INPUT: {{$input}}
LANGUAGECODES: {{$languagecodes}}
EXCEPTIONS: {{$exceptions}}
OUTPUT:
````

**my actual outputs displaying the random stuff it adds**

[image: Outputs from ChatGPT with correct and wrong outputs]

And in my prompt, I tell it to output in a JSON and just JSON format as displayed in my example OUTPUT... But it still sometimes adds random stuff.

## Question

How to force it to just output the actual json object?

Comment: Do you use `guidance`? Also, you expect a list of JSONs. Edit; Also, you could use function calling for this task.

Comment: @doneforaiur Don't know what `guidance` is. But I will look it up, also Function calling I will look up too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChatGPT has JSON Mode.

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
response_format={ "type": "json_object" },
messages=[
{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant 
designed to output JSON."},
{"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"}
 ]
)
print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

[OpenAI Documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/json-mode?lang=python)

Comment: Recommendations are nice, but a valid example for the question at hand would be even nicer. :^)